# Machine Learning Tensor flow and sentiment analysis

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I'd like to make a machine learning with Tensorflow about sentiment analysis, I know it's possible to do machine learning with tensorflow but is it possible to make machine learning suited for sentiment analysis ? I know it's possible to do sentiment analysis with Convolutional Neuronal Network (Deep learning so) with Tensor flow but I'm looking for a solution that only uses Machine learning algorithm, not deep learning.

Would you know great tutorials to begin a GCP Machine Learning project ? Is it possible to begin a GCP Machine Learning Project without using google API or Tensorflow (just in "regular" python but which can be linked to other services like google big query, data prep) ?

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

In general it wouldn't make much sense to use TensorFlow for non-deep learning solutions. You can always try [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) for implementing other machine learning techniques with python, but I do not think that you could get far with sentiment analysis this way. For a nice introduction on sentiment analysis with TensorFlow I would suggest to go through [this](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/perform-sentiment-analysis-with-lstms-using-tensorflow) guide.

As for machine learning on google cloud platform: there is a number of APIs hosted in the platform which use pre-built models, including [cloud natural language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/) which has an [analyzeSentiment](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/documents/analyzeSentiment) method. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/sentiment-tutorial) you can find a python tutorial on how to do sentiment analysis using the python client library of the cloud natural language api.

If you still want to try and build your own model, you can train (with either [scikit-learn](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/) or [tensorflow](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/)), deploy and then use it for predictions on the cloud with the [google cloud machine learning engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/). As for tutorials, I would suggest that you visit the official documentations of any of the above products/services, you will find there comprehensive step-by-step guides for all levels.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , I will probably use the google cloud natural language :)